# How can I set a variable in the MediaWiki

Tags: variables, wikipedia, wiki

I'm looking for an oppertunity to set a variable in the wikipedia code.

something like this

year1 = "2002"

and then just to write year1 instead of 2002. Because if I want to change 2002 to 2004 I don't have to change twenty times the 2002, just only year1 once.
I Really hope you can help me.

Thank you so much for your time. :)

Best Regards
Dante

Comment: Welcome userN. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). If you revise you post accordingly you may get better answers.

Comment: For example, what exactly you mean by "_Wikipedia code_." Within what context are you "_coding_?" Unless you are working on the underlying [Wiki Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_software) you are generally just working in [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) which, as a rule, doesn't support variables. Although, Wikipedia does have [Magic Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words) with some preset variables. Not likely what you seek. Best of luck.

Comment: (Regarding @ScottWelker 's comment) MediaWiki pages don't use Markdown, they use [Wikitext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wikitext) which has a similar purpose and some similarities in syntax but is a different markup system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mediawiki the software platform for Wikipedia offers a feature called [Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Template), which is equivalent to macro in programming context.
As per this you can create a page called Template:year1 with the contents "2002". Then in the article pages whenever you use {{year1}},  it will be replaced with its definition when the article page is presented.  If you need to change the value to 2004, you can change in the template page and all the article pages which use the template will be updated, when they are rendered.

Comment: I was unaware Media Wiki supported [Transclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Transclusion). Good to know. 1 up vote. I can use this. Helps keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).